# How can KVM be located by Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, android, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

When running the emulator, Android Studio reports the following message:

> Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
>
> CPU acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine
>   (/dev/kvm is missing)

However, KVM **is installed** as shown by the following:

> which kvm
>
> /usr/bin/kvm

Thanks...

Answer (score 14):

See the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

In short:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd
sudo adduser `id -un` kvm
```

Then log out and back in again, and check that it is working by running:

```
virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

Some more instructions from Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator

Comment: Got it, I've not enabled VT on BIOS.

Comment: Seems like a good direction

Comment: Should be marked as an answer I think

Comment: I did all that, and I still have the poster's problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem. I managed to fix it after minimal fuss by enabling virtual technology in the BIOS settings. It may be a slightly different method for different computers but on my HP Pavillion Laptop you simply press <kbd>F10</kbd> at start up to get the BIOS options. Then find the tab which allows you to set VT to enabled. As soon as this is done (assuming you have kvm), it works. Just restart and run in terminal.

```
kvm-ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was because of the modprobe:

```
whk @ whk-MS-7817: ~ $ sudo kvm-ok
[sudo] password for whk:
INFO: / dev / kvm does not exist
HINT: sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep () moddep could not open file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/modules.dep.bin'
```

I found the same error message here:https://dainaccio.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/how-to-solve-wifi-not-working-in-a-fresh-installed-linux-mint-17-sony-vaio-atheros-ath9k/

I checked the version of my kernel:

```
whk @ whk-MS-7817: ~ $ uname -mrs
3.13.0-43-generic Linux x86_64
```

It was the same version of the post so talves was a bug, so I proceeded to repair:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0-43
```

And presto!

```
whk @ whk-MS-7817: ~ $ sudo kvm-ok
INFO: / dev / kvm does not exist
HINT: sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU Supports KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Now reboot and working properly. Tested in Android Studio 1.0.2 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

After **installing KVM** like *Ralf* demonstrated in his answer above, you've got to enable Virtual Technology (VT) on Bios.

Press F10 on boot to access your BIOS setting on your machine. (*This might be different depending on your machine*)

[image: Example using HP EliteBook 8440p]

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and in the end it was a BIOS issue. The problem is that you have disabled the virtualization option.

To solve it, you have to enter BIOS setup and activate this option.